# Use placement new to create a static const pointer to a static memory buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, placement-new

I'd like to initialize a static, constant pointer to an object of class type MyClass2, which is stored in a static data buffer in class MyClass1 when it is instantiated.

This doesn't work:

```
class MyClass1 {
   public:
       MyClass1()
       {
           _my_class_2_ptr = new (_my_class_2_buf) MyClass2();
       }

   private:
      static MyClass2 *const  _my_class_2_ptr;
      static char *_my_class_2_buf = new char[sizeof(MyClass2)]; 
};
```

Is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your variables are static, you can't initialize them in constructor. It just doesn't make sense! What you want to do is something like

(in header)

```
class MyClass1 {
   // member    
   public:
      static MyClass2 *const  _my_class_2_ptr;
      static std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(MyClass2)> _my_class_2_buf; 
};
```

(in cpp)

```
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(MyClass2)> MyClass1::_my_class_2_buf;
MyClass2* const MyClass1::_my_class_2_ptr = new (&MyClass1::_my_class_2_buf) MyClass2;
```

Comment: Understood. Since static variables are common to the class, I guess it wouldn't make sense to re-initialize them each time the class was instantiated. However, in this case I wanted MyClass1 to be a singleton, so as it can only be instantiated once anyway, I suppose it wouldn't really matter.

Comment: You are missing `type` for std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type - very bad !

Comment: @DieterLücking he's using `aligned_storage_t` not `aligned_storage`

Comment: @DieterLücking, I am not :) (in the declaration, at least)

Comment: Anyway, you do not need `std::aligned_storage_t`, a plain `char storage[sizeof(MyClass2)];` will do it too.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the definitions and intializations of the `static` member variables outside the class.

```
class MyClass1 {
   public:
       MyClass1() {}

   private:
      static MyClass2 *const  _my_class_2_ptr;
      static char *_my_class_2_buf; 
};

char *MyClass2::_my_class_2_buf = new char[sizeof(MyClass2)]; 
MyClass2 *const  MyClass1::_my_class_2_ptr = new (_my_class_2_buf) MyClass2();
```